# Rails: "currency" is escaped/transformed to "¤cy" without my asking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have hit upon a very strange thing in my Rails 3.2.9 app - when I render this:

```
render inline: BusinessesController.checkout_page_url(...)
```

with this method:

```
def self.checkout_page_url(business, order_number)
  url = ''
  # ...
  url << 'currency=' << conf['currency'] << '&'
  # ...
  puts url
  return url
end
```

then the resulting url is rendered just fine in the console (`puts url`):

```
... currency=EUR& ...
```

but the rendered string in the browser reads:

```
... ¤cy=EUR& ...
```

I've tried calling `.html_safe` on the string before rendering it, but didn't change a thing. When changing `currency` to `curency` (with a typo) then everything's fine.

What's going on?

Comment: When you use the typo, is that in reference to `conf['curency']` or in the string `curency=` or both?

Comment: @mbratch only in the string. meaning, it has something to do with how strings are processed, and i suspect that "currency" is somehow escaped or something like that.

Comment: OFF TOPIC: rails 3.2 versions below 3.2.13 have major security vulnerabilities - see https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aweblog.rubyonrails.org&q=%5BSEC%5D - You should upgrade to latest 3.2 ASAP

Comment: @house9 thanks! the app is not deployed currently, i'll keep that in mind for later.

Comment: please don't wait - update Gemfile with rails version `3.2.14` and then run `bundle update rails` - read this if you want to get totally freaked out: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2013/01/31/what-the-rails-security-issue-means-for-your-startup/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the HTML code for ¤ is &curren.
Check http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm.

So the browsers are replacing it with the symbol.

To get around it try doing:

```
<%= h url%>
```

in your view. Where 'h' is an old rails helper that is used for escaping.

Comment: ha great thanks! actually i suspected this a few minutes ago (because the '&' was also gone). awesome!